# pam_lastlog does not write to /var/log/lastlog

Tags: linux, centos, pam

I am using [pamela](https://github.com/minrk/pamela) with JupyterHub to open PAM sessions for my users. I am on CentOS 8 and I am using the login service. I can see in /var/log/secure

> pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user testuser by (uid=0)

and in /var/log/messages

> systemd[1]: Started Session 8341 of user testuser

Furthermore there are no erros logged in /var/log/{messages|secure|audit/audit.log}. But with a new user succesfull logged in to JupyterHub, the lastlog command still says that this user has never logged in. So I think I miss some requirements for pam_lastlog in order to write information to /var/log/lastlog. pam_open_session is called in a subprocess with root privileges. Maybe this subprocess needs to be tied to a pts or tty in order to write useful information to /var/log/lastlog? This is the /etc/pamd.d/login file:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       substack     system-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_console.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
```

this is in /etc/pamd.d/postlogin

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authselect is run.

session optional                   pam_umask.so silent
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service !~ gdm* service !~ su* quiet
session [default=1]                pam_lastlog.so nowtmp showfailed
session optional                   pam_lastlog.so silent noupdate showfailed
```

and this is in /etc/pamd.d/system-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authselect is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass use_authtok nullok sha512 shadow
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

Answer (score 0):

You `/etc/pam.d/postlogin` file contains the `nowtmp` directive on this line:

`session [default=1]                pam_lastlog.so nowtmp showfailed`

From `$ man pam_lastlog`:

```
       nowtmp
           Don't update the wtmp entry.
```

The `last` command uses the `/var/log/wtmp` file while the `lastlog` command uses the `/var/log/lastlog` file.

`lastlog` is usually much smaller than the `wtmp` file as it only records the very last login for each user. `wtmp` records a **history** of **all** the login time and dates for a user.

There doesn't seem to be a directive in `pam_lastlog.so` manual page which can switch off logging to the lastlog so this should by all accounts be working. Note, there is a directive to  with the `nowtmp` directive.

You can however, switch off historical logins written to `wtmp` so perhaps try removing just the `nowtmp` directive and see that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

For the login service, it is the postlogin line with silent, noupdate & showfailed that is used. `noupdate` apparently means that `pam_lastlog` should not update *any file*. So this line does not allow `pam_lastlog` to update lastlog.

It *does* still seem to record failed logins somewhere, but not successful ones. This results in the failed login count only being reset when a successful login happens using the `gdm`* or `su`* services.